# x axis text overlapping in matlab

Tags: matlab, text, overlap

My x axis text are overlapping. I am using this code--

```
   clear all
   A=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]';
 b=1:length(A);
 figure(1)
 bar(A)
 title('Loss Diagram')
 xlabel('Loss factor')
 ylabel('kWh/year','fontsiz`enter code here`e',20)
 grid on

set(gca,'Xtick',b,'XtickLabel',{'Horizntl Global Irr. ' 'Effective irr. on coll. ' 'Array nominal energy ' 'PV module loss ' 'charge controller loss  ' 'Battery efficiency loss ' 'converter loss '},'fontsize',14);
```

![matlab image]http://filepi.com/i/HeQt8pE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't ask a question, but I assume you want some way of displaying your x-axis labels without overlapping.

A solution is [rotateXLabels.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27812-rotatexlabels--ax--angle--varargin--), which is also build into the newest Matlab versions.

Here's an example:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]';
b=1:length(A);

figure(1)
bar(A)

title('Loss Diagram')
xlabel('Loss factor')
ylabel('kWh/year', 'FontSize', 20)
grid on

set(gca,'Xtick',b,'XtickLabel', ...
    {'Horizntl Global Irr. ', 'Effective irr. on coll. ', ...
    'Array nominal energy ' 'PV module loss ' 'charge controller loss ', ...
    'Battery efficiency loss ' 'converter loss '}, 'FontSize', 14);

rotateXLabels( gca(), 45 )
```

Which produces:
[image]

Comment: In new Matlab versions you just use `set(gca, 'XTickLabelRotation', 45)`

Comment: Specifically R2014b and newer for the built-in